# Is there query API for Google Photos (photos.google.com)

Tags: google-photos

We can choose cat photos taken in a location in the google photos app, but I wonder if there is any API for that?

I did some search and people suggested we can use the old google+ API for upload, but I'm looking into getting a list of photos that match the search.

Or, perhaps to get a list of photos in a given public photo albums?

Comment: Find a easy way to do it? Seems really hard. thx

Comment: no, there is still no easy way, but with the google photos app 2017, you can do that in the app